# Checking if elements are part of list and creating a new list

Tags: python, list, gspread

So I have two lists (it is extracted from google sheets via gspread library)
One column from the google spreadsheets had all the brand names. I got this whole column and created a list called 'approved_brand'.
I got another column and called it 'approved_seller'.
These brands and sellers (in the grand scheme of things) is a list of approved sellers for each brand.

I have another spreadsheet where there are the list of actual sellers selling the particular brand.
My objective is to see if the actual sellers for the particular brand are approved or not.

For example:
`approved_brand=[1,2,3,4,5]`, `approved_seller=[a,b,c,d,e]`
(meaning a is approved to sell 1, b is approved for 2, c for 3, etc.)

`brand=[1,7,8,9,4,5]`, `seller=[a,d,f,g,g,e]`
After checking, you should get two lists that returns `[1,5]` and `[a,e]` meaning out of all the sellers in those brands, only a was approved to sell 1 and e was approved to sell 4.

Get lists for approved brands and sellers.

```
approved_brand=referenceTable.col_values(1)
del approved_brand[0]
approved_seller=referenceTable.col_values(2)
del approved_seller[0]
```

Get all the brands and sellers from the data stored in google spreadsheets (list of actual brands and corresponding sellers)

```
brand=inputfile.col_values(2)
del brand[0]
seller=inputfile.col_values(4)
del seller[0]

for i in range(len(brand)):
    if brand[i] in approved_brand and seller[i] in approved_seller:
        approvedBrandInActual.append(brand[i])
        approvedSellerInActual.append(seller[i])
```

This last for loop is not working as intended.

Comment: What is the for loop doing now, and are the variables in the lists real, or are those stand-ins for something else?

Comment: The variables in the list that I mentioned on top was just an example. Right now, there are a bunch of brands and sellers in the list. What I am trying to do with the for loop is this. I want to go through each index of the brand list and seller list simultaneously. if each brand and seller list are within the approved brand and approved seller list, I create a new list and add it to that list.

Comment: Can you revise your example? Isn't `e` was approved to sell `5` if I am not wrong? Also length of `approved_brand` and `brand` are different.

Comment: Sorry, I made the mistake in on e being approved for 5. The reason the length of brand and approved_brand are different is because there are only a few approved brands while there are many brands out there. The approval process has to do with making sure that the brand as well as the seller are both approved. For example, lets say that Seller A was selling Nike. If Nike isn't part of the approved brand, then this shouldnt be passed to the new list.

Comment: New example: approved_brand=[Brand A, Brand B, Brand D, Brand F], for these approved brands are the corresponding approved_seller=[Seller1, Seller5, Seller,6, Seller7]. In the marketplace, these are the brands and sellers that exist: brand=[Brand A, Brand D, Brand G, Brand F, Brand F] with corresponding sellers=[Seller1,Seller6, Seller1,Seller7,Seller8]. It should return: approvedBrandInActual=[Brand A,Brand D,Brand F] with corresponding approvedSellerInActual=[Seller1,Seller6,Seller7]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For iterating through lists simultaneously, use `zip`. Go through lists and check if corresponding `brand` and `seller` are within the approved lists.

```
approved_brand=[1,2,3,4,5]
approved_seller=['a','b','c','d','e']

brand=[1,7,8,9,4,5] 
seller=['a','d','f','g','g','e'] 

br, sr = [], []
for b, s in zip(brand, seller):
    if (b, s) in zip(approved_brand, approved_seller):
        br.append(b)
        sr.append(s)

print(br)  # [1, 5]
print(sr)  # ['a', 'e']
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you! hopefully, things work out as intended!